# Install - AWS CLI on jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm a newbie to Jenkins and have started learning it.

Actually I have been trying to use AWS command in a shell script and running it using Jenkins. But it says - **aws command not found.**

I have installed all the required plugins and did restarted the jenkins. But it is still the same.

All Enabled Plugins:

```
Amazon Web Services SDK :: All
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
This plugin provides all AWS SDK for Java modules not packaged as standalone plugins.
Report an issue with this plugin


Amazon Web Services SDK :: CloudFormation
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
CloudFormation module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: CodeBuild
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
CodeBuild module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: EC2
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
EC2 module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: ECR
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
ECR module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: ECS
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
ECS module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: EFS
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
EFS module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: Elastic Beanstalk
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
Elastic Beanstalk module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: IAM
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
EC2 module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: Logs
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
Logs module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: Minimal
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
Minimal modules for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: SNS
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
SNS module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: SQS
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
SQS module for the AWS SDK for Java.


Amazon Web Services SDK :: SSM
Version1.12.287-357.vf82d85a_6eefd
SSM module for the AWS SDK for Java.
```

I was just trying to run - **aws help** command and got the following error

```
+ aws help
/tmp/jenkins1806878893080825405.sh: 2: aws: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any leads on how to fix this would be really appreciated.

Comment: ...I have installed all the required plugins...you provide no names, no logs, no context. it is always hard to provide any advice when it is not clear what did you exactly do.

Comment: hey, I have updated the question and i was just trying to run aws help command nothing much

Comment: `aws cli` is a cmd tool , you need to install on your jenkins controller or agent where you execute `aws help`, or you use awscli docker image as your pipeline agent.  I don't think aws jenkins plugin includes the tool.

Comment: thanks for the inputs @yong could you please share any links that i can refer for that